# Present perfect or past perfect?

Tags: tense

I have come across this:

Have you used a dictionary before posting your question?

Is it correct? Or should it be

Had you used a dictionary before posting your question?

Comment: You're right. With the finished simple past time, "before posting your question", present perfect is incorrect. "Had you used" is correct-ish, but "Did you use" is the most natural.

Comment: @gotube "Have you used" is not correct in this context. It might be a proper grammatical form in certain contexts, but it does not fit the intended meaning here. Your "did" is the correct answer.

Comment: @JeffMorrow, That's what I said, innit? Or did you mean to say that "had you used" is not correct?

Comment: Yes, I meant to say "Had you used." Sorry for any confusion my carelessness caused.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct.

> Did you use a dictionary before posting this question

is correct. In general, people whose native language uses the present perfect as a general tense to express past time, overuse the present perfect tense in English.

Notice that I am not saying "Have you done" or "Had you done" are always grammatically improper. They are not. But preceding a participial phrase introduced by "before," they are not idiomatic, and I suspect they are ungrammatical. If not ungrammatical, they are very rare.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use the word "have" here, it sounds out of place to me (an American).

Instead, I would say a better question is:

> Had you used a dictionary before posting your question?

or

> Did you use a dictionary before posting your question?

Of these two, both could be correct but they have slightly different meanings.

> Did you use a dictionary before posting your question?

means "In this particular instance, did you look at a dictionary for help on this question?"

> Had you used a dictionary before posting your question?

means "Before you posted the question, had you ever (in your life) used a dictionary?"

Comment: "Had you used" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @JeffMorrow why wrong? It's not plain to me. Griffin's gloss of the "Had you..." example feels accurate to me

Comment: @gotube It is wrong because that is not the intended meaning of the question. The question is not whether it could ever be correct to use such a construction, but whether it is correct in the context of the OP's example. Moreover, the natural way to convey the alternative thought is "Did you ever use a dictionary." We need to consider what is helpful to the OP.

Comment: Agreed. *Had you used* is incorrect given the context here.

Comment: I have heard different opinions on this question. Some natives indeed accept "the past perfect", others don't.

Comment: I like your answer anyway! Upvoted!